# HTTP packages are not sending

Tags: c++, macos, http, httprequest, cfnetwork

I write my application for MAC OS X Mavericks. It's must be application, which can send POST and GET requests to the server. First of all, I try to send a POST request. But, unfortunately, it doesn't work and I don't know why. When I try to catch packages with sniffer WireShark, it shows that there are no packages has sended. This is my code:

```
UInt32 Login(wchar_t* wstrIpAddress)
{
    size_t size = wstrIpAddress.length();

    //create request body
    CFStringRef bodyString = CFSTR("");
    CFDataRef bodyData = CFStringCreateExternalRepresentation(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                      bodyString,
                                                      kCFStringEncodingUTF8,
                                                      0);
    if(bodyData == NULL)
    {
        cout << "CFStringCreateExternalRepresentation() could not convert the characters to the specified encoding. "
        "Error code: "
        << errno << endl;
        return 2;
    }

    //create headers
    CFStringRef headerFieldName = CFSTR("Content-Type");
    CFStringRef headerFieldValue = CFSTR("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=base64");

    //fix coding wstrIpAddress from wstring to UInt8
    CFStringEncoding encoding =
    (CFByteOrderLittleEndian == CFByteOrderGetCurrent()) ? kCFStringEncodingUTF32LE : kCFStringEncodingUTF32BE;

    CFIndex wstrIpAddressLen = (wcslen(wstrIpAddress.c_str())) * sizeof(wchar_t);

    CFStringRef myUrl = CFStringCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                        (UInt8*)wstrIpAddress.c_str(),
                                        wstrIpAddressLen,
                                        encoding,
                                        false);
    if(myUrl == NULL)
    {
        cout << "CFStringCreateWithBytes() had a problem with creating the object. Error code: " << errno << endl;
        return 3;
    }

    //CFStringRef urlEscaped = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, myUrl, NULL, NULL, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, myUrl, 0);
    if(url == NULL)
    {
        cout << "CFURLCreateWithString() had a problem with creating the object. Error code: " << errno << endl;
        return 4;
    }

    CFStringRef requestMethod = CFSTR("POST");
    CFHTTPMessageRef myRequest = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, requestMethod, url, kCFHTTPVersion1_1);
    if(myRequest == NULL)
    {
        cout << "CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest() had a problem with creating the object. Error code: " << errno << endl;
        return 5;
    }

    CFDataRef bodyDataExt = CFStringCreateExternalRepresentation(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                         bodyString,
                                                         kCFStringEncodingUTF8,
                                                         0);
    if(bodyDataExt == NULL)
    {
        cout << "CFStringCreateExternalRepresentation() could not convert the characters to the specified encoding. "
        "Error code: "
        << errno << endl;
        return 6;
    }

    CFHTTPMessageSetBody(myRequest, bodyDataExt);
    CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue(myRequest, headerFieldName, headerFieldValue);
    CFReadStreamRef myReadStream = CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, myRequest);
    //CFErrorRef copyError = CFReadStreamCopyError(myReadStream);
    //cout << copyError << endl;
    CFRelease(myRequest);
    myRequest = NULL;

    //you could release the CFHTTP request object immediately after calling CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest
    //Because the read stream opens a socket connection with the server specified by the myUrl parameter when the CFHTTP request was created, some
    //amount of time must be allowed to pass before the stream is considered to be open

    //Opening the read stream also causes the request to be serialized and sent
    Boolean bRes = CFReadStreamOpen(myReadStream);
    if(bRes == FALSE)
    {
        CFStreamError myErr = CFReadStreamGetError(myReadStream);
        // An error has occurred.
        if (myErr.domain == kCFStreamErrorDomainPOSIX) {
        // Interpret myErr.error as a UNIX errno.
        } 
        else if (myErr.domain == kCFStreamErrorDomainMacOSStatus) {
        // Interpret myErr.error as a MacOS error code.
        OSStatus macError = (OSStatus)myErr.error;
        // Check other error domains.
        }
        cout << "ReadStreamOpen error with error code: " << errno << endl;;
        return 7;
    }
    //UInt32 myErrCode = CFHTTPMessageGetResponseStatusCode(myReadStream);
    /*if(myErrCode != 200)
    {
        cout << "Request faild\n" << endl;
        return 1;
    }*/

    //release the message objects
    CFRelease(url);
    CFRelease(bodyString);
    CFRelease(bodyData);
    CFRelease(headerFieldName);
    CFRelease(headerFieldValue);
    CFRelease(bodyDataExt);
    bodyDataExt = NULL;
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Did you step through with a debugger already?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, yes, of course.... But it didn't help me(((

Comment: I find answer, but can't post it because of my reputation can't allow me((( What I can do??

Comment: You should be able to answer your own question. There's no reputation restriction IIRC. Unless you're banned from answering generally, there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

1. Address to the server, for example, must be in such format:
   http://10.0.0.25, but **NOT** only ip like this -> 10.0.0.25.
2. We also must check status code from response, that guarantees correct connection.

   ```
   UInt32 myErrCode = CFHTTPMessageGetResponseStatusCode(myReadStream);
   if(myErrCode != 200)
   {
       cout << "Request faild\n" << endl;
       return 1;
   }
   ```